# Very low quality flag declined arguing 'apple fails' is technically accurate

Tags: discussion, flags, declined-flags, low-quality-posts

Is this answer not the poster child of very low quality?

From the [*Unwind segue not working*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23721818/unwind-segue-not-working) question, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23721818/unwind-segue-not-working/29022849#29022849) was provided by user [*ihateapple*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4665248/ihateapple), which is the only answer this user has ever left at this site:

> [image: answer]

My very low quality flag was declined, citing the answer was technically accurate.

> [image: flag]

In my mind, that's quite a stretch.  Besides the unhelpful, derogatory, unsalvageable nature of the answer, this answer doesn't contribute much more than stating: *Add stuff to your file*

Just to top this off, this answer was even edited to "improve" it by making the file names bold:

> [image: edit]

Regardless whether you argue this is technically correct, should this not be put to death in the review queues?

Comment: @JK.:  The argument being made is if it's even an *attempt* at an answer.  To me it reads like someone is just being a troll.  It's an answer that's primed for someone with full delete privileges to handle, though.

Comment: Your question title here appears to be ... inaccurate, and I think you've seriously misread something. The flag decline message is specifically **not** trying to claim that this answer *is* technically accurate. Rather, it's saying that if it *is* technically inaccurate, that's not a matter for diamond mods to handle. In this particular case, there's some rather unhelpful rhetoric, sure, but as long as you treat all the slams as metasyntactic variables, the answer appears to be plausible enough. And it would be a little silly for someone to take personal offense at Apple-bashing, so let it go.

Comment: I think moderator should leave the VLQ queue for community member to handle. Without the queue, there is very little chance for 3 people with enough privilege to come across the answer and cast delete vote.

Comment: @NathanTuggy While I don't take offense, my understanding of Stack Overflow is to keep garbage out.  Fighting to keep answers like these does not represent a community I want to be a part of, nor find valuable.  As well, I don't understand why this didn't end up community moderated.  After 1,427 helpful flags, this is my second declined, and might be the last time I bother.

Comment: It didn't get moderated by the community because LQP has had a lot of trouble with overloading lately (courtesy cc @nhahtdh). If the diamonds weren't handling the slack, it would look more like the CV queue. No one wants that.

Comment: It didn't get community moderated because the community agrees--apple sucks just that badly.

Comment: @nhahtdh they do... at least for an hour, before the flag moves to the moderator queue.

Comment: "After 1,427 helpful flags, this is my second declined, and might be the last time I bother." Oh well, I guess those 1,427 helpful flags didn't matter after all.

Comment: @BoltClock Negativity both in helping this site and learning its correct use doesn't encourage future contribution.  I'm not after rewards - just a site I still value.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I declined that, and I apologize. That was clearly a mistake or misclick, and should have been removed. That answer was obvious trolling, and I know that subject matter, so I have no idea why I didn't delete that. A "very low quality" flag should have been enough for me to be able to delete that.

Thanks for bringing it back up so the community could correct my mistake.

Answer (score 11):

In the arms race between spam and spam detection, spam occasionally fools even human detectors.

Phishing is specifically designed to fool humans.

And here, we have a troll post which successfully fooled a human spam detector... on the other hand, trolling isn't particular effective if no one understands your derogatory message.

Bringing this to meta and explaining that it is a troll post was the right decision, it's now been deleted by trusted community members who evaluated the evidence and agreed with you.

Unfortunately, moderators / queue handlers aren't able to read your mind, the ones who declined your flag didn't evaluate your evidence, but started from scratch.  And the poster did conceal the troll nature fairly effectively, so the flag reviewer(s) misjudged.

Comment: Hrm. So, bringing it to meta is a better approach than raising an 'in need of moderator intervention' flag with a detailed explanation?

Comment: When explanation is required, yes meta is better.

Comment: But normally no.  Normally "moderator intervention" flags just work fine, and when they do, they are FAR more efficient.

Comment: Community intervention was needed here.

Comment: @JasonSturges Well, no. All that was needed was for you to raise a custom flag explaining that your flag was declined, and why you disagree with the decision.